# How to reuse field values in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, oop, methods, software-design

I have a method which does calculations on different Road data. I want to reuse the method, but to be able to change the specific road data.

In the example below I use the the `data.Road_1_256` data. I want to call the method, but be able to choose what data I use. For example, change `Road_1_256` to `Road_1_2048`, and keep the rest of the method the same.

How can I do this?

```
private static void Task_2(DataHandler data, BubbleSort BubbS, QuickSort QS, HeapSort HS, InsertionSort IS, )
{
    // Call ascending and descending methods using quick sort (data set 256)
    Console.WriteLine("- USING QUICK SORT -");
    Console.WriteLine("- Ascending and Descending Order 10th elements (ROAD_1_256) -");
    var road_1_256_aq = QS.QuickSortAscending(data.Road_1_256, "yes"); GetNthElementsOfArray(road_1_256_aq, 10);
    var road_1_256_dq = QS.QuickSortDescending(data.Road_1_256); GetNthElementsOfArray(road_1_256_dq, 10);

    Console.WriteLine("\n\n- Ascending and Descending Order 10th elements (ROAD_2_256) -");
    var road_2_256_aq = QS.QuickSortAscending(data.Road_2_256, "yes"); GetNthElementsOfArray(road_2_256_aq, 10);
    var road_2_256_dq = QS.QuickSortDescending(data.Road_2_256); GetNthElementsOfArray(road_2_256_dq, 10);

    Console.WriteLine("\n\n- Ascending and Descending Order 10th elements (ROAD_3_256) -");
    var road_3_256_aq = QS.QuickSortAscending(data.Road_3_256, "yes"); GetNthElementsOfArray(road_3_256_aq, 10);
    var road_3_256_dq = QS.QuickSortDescending(data.Road_3_256); GetNthElementsOfArray(road_3_256_dq, 10);
```

Comment: Maybe more code, but this looks very upside down to me. Why are you passing so many parameters? Why are they Sorts? What's with the magic strings?

Eh, in fact, maybe this should be a more complete example and on Code Review.

Comment: This is related to a now-deleted question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923463/how-to-shorten-lots-of-method-calls-in-c which had more code

Comment: Do you really use a method named `GetNthElementsOfArray()` rather than looking up by index?

Answer (score 1):

You could change what you're passing into the method to be the actual fields themselves:

```
    private static void Task_2(int[] road1, int[] road2, int[] road3, BubbleSort BubbS, QuickSort QS, HeapSort HS, InsertionSort IS, )
    {
         var road_1_aq = QS.QuickSortAscending(road1, "yes"); GetNthElementsOfArray(road_1_aq, 10);
         var road_1_256_dq = QS.QuickSortDescending(road1); GetNthElementsOfArray(road_1_dq, 10);

    // ...
```